# Read XML file lines and read them in as strings in java.

Tags: java, xml, string, stringbuffer

I have following file with xml data in it.  I don't want to parse this data and want to put that information into a Java String or StringBuffer.

```
<Node number="5"> 

<line/> 
<line center="1">** DATA **</line> 
<line/> <line/> 
<line>Data1: %Data%</line> 
<line>Data2 : %Data%</line> 
<line/> 
<line align="left">%DATA%</line> 
<line align="right">%DATA%</line> 
<line/> <line/> 
</Node>
```

I want that xml data in a java data structure as-is so I can manipulate the lines, what structure should I use and how should this be done?

Comment: What do you mean, the same as below? If you just want to read a file line-by-line, there are plenty of ways to do that.

Comment: If you just want to read the file see http://qwerky-qwerky.blogspot.co.uk/2012/12/basics-reading-file.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm understanding what you're looking for, [Files.readAllLines](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllLines%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.charset.Charset%29) is the simplest solution (if Java 7 is available). Create a `Path` pointing to your file, and call `readAllLines` with it and the character set of the file as parameters to get a `List` of `Strings`.

Answer (score 2):

Try loading the file into a FileInputStream like this:

```
FileInputStream ins=new FileInputStream("your-file-name");
byte[] bytearray=new byte[1024];
String file=new String(bytearray);
System.out.print(file);
```

This puts the xml data in a new String variable `file`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `jCabi` libraries to split it.

```
XML xml = new XMLDocument(new File("file.xml"));
    String xmlToString = xml.toString();
    System.out.println("XML as String using JCabi library");
    System.out.println(xmlToString);
```